# Error Key Hashes login con facebook

Tags: android, android-layout, login, facebook, facebook-api

Tengo que iniciar sesión en facebook con un botón y seguí las instrucciones que te dan en facebook developers y cuando probe la aplicación la primera vez si funciono correctamente, pero cuando la volví a probar me salia este error
[image: Error de login]

Y las key que tengo que registre en la aplicación de facebook las genere con las instrucciones que te da facebook
[image: key's]

Comment: la key del error no coincide con las keys de tu segunda foto

Comment: Luis, agrega el Key Hash que muestra tu aplicación al mostrar el error en tu aplicación Facebook. El problema es básicamente que tu aplicación esta firmada con otro Keystore que obviamente tiene otro KeyHash y este no esta registrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que el Key Hash que configuras en tu aplicación facebook, esta relacionado al Keystore con el que tu aplicación es firmada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si usas el `debug.keystore` tendrá un  Key hash diferente al `Keystore`  que uses para firmar tus aplicaciones en producción.

Incluso si obtuviste el Key Hash de tu `debug.keystore` y lo borras, este se regeneraría con otro Key Hash, lo mismo si cambias de pc.

Si no conoces el Key hash con el que firmas tu aplicación, te sugiero [obtenerlo nuevamente de tu keystore](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/):

Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64
```

OS x

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

---

En este caso el Key Hash que se obtiene, es uno que no esta registrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes agregarlo a tu aplicación Facebook.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvio mucho, ya pude arreglarlo gracias!!

Comment: Excelente Luis, me da mucho gusto!, saludos!

Comment: @LuisUribe Puedes ayudarnos por favor con esta pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161914/generar-key-en-api-de-facebook-para-loggiarme-desde-ionic

Comment: @Jorgesys  Puedes ayudarnos por favor con esta pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161914/generar-key-en-api-de-facebook-para-loggiarme-desde-ionic