# Generar Key en api de Facebook para loggiarme desde IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial:

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework

en un momento es necesario crear un keyhash, el asunto es que no sé en IONIC en que momento o cuando se crea.
con este comando creo el keyhash para facebook:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore" | 
"C:\Users\yeisonvelez\Desktop\open\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | 
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\open\bin\openssl" base64
```

cuando se ejecuta este comando me pide una contraseña, y no sé cual es. tampoco estoy seguro qué es `androiddebugkey`. El nombre de mi app es `io.ionic.starter` y el apk generado  "android-debug" por si se necesita saber esta información.

el problema es que el keyhash de facebook no coincide con el comando que acabo de ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

El keyhash es un string de 28 caracteres que facebook utiliza para autenticar las interacciones entre tu aplicación y facebook. Esta llave es única.
Sin esta llave no es posible que tu aplicación funcione correctamente con facebook.
Para el desarrollo de la app y para verificar el funcionamiento del flujo de tu aplicación con la integración de facebook, Android genera una llave de prueba "androiddebugkey" con la que firma las aplicaciones en "debug", para llevarla a modo producción será necesario que generes tu propia clave. 
 
Para "androiddebugkey" la contraseña es "android".

Te dejó unos links para que investigues un poco mas del tema: 
[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk) 
[Link1 (Android developers)](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) 
[Documentación ionic v1](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html) 
[Stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102309/error-key-hashes-login-con-facebook?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash)

Recuerda que es bueno investigar si existe una pregunta similar a la tuya para evitar redundar en los foros!

Espero haberte ayudado. 
Saludos!